# Error near CASE when converting bit (1/0 or true/false) to Yes/No

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Doing this in C# but testing it in SQL Server until it works

Here is my code with a few edits to column names (privacy) but the gist is there, I get an error near case.

Every column with product in it will eventually be changed to yes/no

```
SELECT  c.customer_name ,
        c.addr_line_1 ,
        c.addr_line_2 ,
        c.city ,
        c.state ,
        c.zip ,
        ci.title ,
        ci.f_name ,
        ci.l_name ,
        ci.email ,
        ci.phone ,
        c.prod1 
        CASE WHEN prod1 = 1 THEN 'Yes'
             ELSE 'No'
        END ,
        c.prod2 ,
        c.prod3 ,
        c.prod4 ,
        c.prod5 ,
        c.prod6
FROM    Customer c
        INNER JOIN ContactInfo ci ON c.customer_id = ci.customer_id
WHERE   ci.title = 'IT'
        AND c.prod1 = 1
```

Getting 'Incorrect Syntax near the keyword 'case' as error, sorry

Comment: Why would you be doing this in `SQL` just to have to port it to `C#` at a later time? They're two different languages (with different syntaxes)...

Comment: Did I miss the part where you specified what error you're getting?

Comment: What's the difference between testing this in the query line and doing it in cmd.COmmandText = "this" and testing on a website? It's a web form I guess I should add

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'case'

Comment: Your "WHERE c.prod1 = 1" clause is going to make your CASE irrelevant

Comment: so it changes 1/0 to yes/no before so I should search by yes/no? also the answer below was right I had the words out of order, something I thought I had checked. also when I end I can't have c.prod1 it has to be just prod1 which i'm not sure why

Comment: @pbrianq No, Task is saying that you might as well just select "Yes" instead of even having a case statement. The `AND c.prod1 = 1` at the end makes your case statement irrelevant

Comment: well the case statement makes it say yes instead of true/false which is more user experience but i couldnt figure out the code

Comment: @pbrianq The `CASE` statement makes it say "Yes/No", but it will never say "No" because of the condition `c.prod = 1`

Comment: ah yes but the way the search will function is the user will choose a primary search column (in this case product 1) and all of the places where product 1 is true will show in the first column, so that column contains all true values. I guess if anything that column will never show no but I'll be using the same case in 6 different variants of the query so for ease I'll add it with the else then 'no' and remove it later. I understand what you and he mean though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is just before `case`. You are using the wrong syntax.

```
ci.phone, c.prod1 case when prod1 = 1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end,
          ^^^^^^^^
```

It should be:

```
ci.phone, case when prod1 = 1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end as prod1,
```

Column name for the case output should be specified at the end of `CASE` statement, not before.

You may see: [CASE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

Comment: Am I correct in thinking it would be best for the use of prod1 to reference the aliased table? i.e. 'case when c.prod1'

Comment: I can do 'case when c.prod1' but in the end as it has to be just prod1. Any idea why?

Comment: @JamieKeeling, May be, I would let OP modify it, if he/she gets an error for ambiguous column reference.

Comment: @pbrianq, the alias you specify should be `prod1`, not `c.prod1`